# Wiping laptop hp aspire one

Tags: linux-mint

I have a hp aspire one laptop Havnt used in some time and the password I thought it was isnt working. I want to wipe the password or the whole laptop but not sure how. It's running on Linux mint 17

Comment: How do i do that

Answer (score 2):

Re-install the OS to wipe everything out; or use `single user mode` to reset the `root` password.

**Edit:**

Reinstall the OS? Since the steps are extensive, you can follow their official guide here: https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For resetting the `root` password:

1. Reboot the OS
2. On the GRUB menu, select the `kernel` and press `e`
3. In the file that opens, goto line that starts with `linux /boot/vmlinuz...` and at the end, add: `rw init=/bin/bash`
4. Press `F10` or `CTRL + X`

This will boot your system and you will be dropped to the `root` shell. From here, it is pretty much simple task to change `root` user password or any other user for that matter (hint: use `passwd` command)

Once you are done, simply type `exit` and the system will reboot again. You can use the new password now to log into the system.

Comment: How do i do that

Comment: See edited section above in my answer